# Compare (display form) information from 2 lists

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, page-layout, display-form, web-part-connection

I would like to 'compare' 2 list items from different lists. (with the same columns)

On the same page I want to show the names(linked to item) (list 1) on the left site. And I want to show the display form of an item after clicking on one of the names. (now it opens in a new window or in a dialog, and than the second one isn't possible)

Then select one on the right and display (the display form ) next to it.

Now you can compare to items yourself.

[image]

I hope my question is clear. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier method as a workaround:

In the list, modify the current view, select 'Preview Pane' under 'Style' section. Then in the list view, we can get relevant item detailed when hover on the item.

Then create a wiki page and insert these two list view web part, set the 'Text Layout' in the FORMAT TEXT tab as 'Two columns' in the page.

Comment: I thought about it myself, to use the Preview Pane. The only downside is that you can't really fix the item. (it changes very easily, and with a big list (in this case) that is longer dan the page, it is not really user friendly.) But maybe this is although the best and simplest workaround.